# Opening modal doubles the request every time user clicks - Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm adding https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal - Jquery Modal. To my project. I added it to my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.modal.min
//= require pickadate/picker
//= require pickadate/picker.date
```

This I included the `jquery.modal.min.js` in my JS Directory. Added this to my link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path, class: "button", rel: "modal:open" %>
```

The good news is, The modal opens but for some reason it's outside my container so it includes the topbar and the footer and it just looks awful. But weirder than that. It doubles the request to the server everytime I click the link? Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I think you should watch for:

1. Turbolinks could be the one that makes the first call, you may try to disable Turbolink for the link tag.
2. I would want to believe the header and footer are being included because the other page being loaded into the modal renders the layout. You may try disabling the layout for the said page and see if that works.